# From string to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert a string to NSDate. And do not understand what is wrong with my code.

```
   dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sun 02 feb 14 12:30"];
    NSLog(@"dateString %@",dateString);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yy HH:mm"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];


    NSLog(@"dateFromString %@",dateFromString);
```

I get nil. I tried with different dates (same format), always nil.
eg. Thu 07 nov 13 12:45

Does anybody see the mistake?

Comment: You don't have to use stringWithFormat if you're just typing a string. You can just use `dateString = @"Sun 02 feb 12 12:30";` not related to problem but just to let you know.

Comment: Probably the device/simulator is set to a wrong region format?

Comment: try this, [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];

Comment: @Ottavio Sgrosso:2014-02-02 12:30:00 +0000. From your code gives this output not nil. Check your simulator time zone..

Comment: it worked with me, i got this: dateString Sun 02 feb 14 12:30
 dateFromString 2014-02-02 12:30:00 +000

Comment: Added [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"]]; as suggested by rckoenes, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the Locale for the date, set the [locale](http://nshipster.com/nslocale/) of the date formatter to english to make sure it know the date is in english:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Sun 02 feb 14 12:30";
NSLog(@"dateString %@",dateString);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yy HH:mm"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"] autorelease]];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"dateFromString %@",dateFromString);
```

Also there is no need to `alloc` the date here `NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];`. If you are not working with ARC you just leaked a `NSDate` object. If you are using ARC remove the `autorelease` from the `NSLocale`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sun 02 feb 14 12:30"];
    NSLog(@"dateString %@",dateString);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yy HH:mm"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [NSDate alloc];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

This code gives as output: dateFromString 2014-02-02 12:30:00 +0000 which is correct.

Comment: Only if you device language is set to english, never forget the set a locale if there are localized words in a date like, `sun` or `feb` in this case. Also there are some other error in the code.

Comment: @rckoenes my device was set to Greek and I got the correct output.

Comment: @NikosM. just luck, mine is set to dutch and did not work. And your code is still leaking the date.